# UTF-8 Parsing error in reading UTF-8 Excel files using PHP-ExcelReader

Tags: php, excel

I’m trying to read and parse a UTF-8 Excel file using the PHPExcelReader but unfortunately this does not work correctly and I receive some ???? Instead of UTF-8 characters. Would you please help me about the instructions about the way to handle this situation? I have used this configuration for my parsing:

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader();
$data->setOutputEncoding('CP1251');
$data->setUTFEncoder('mb');
```

Thanks

Comment: Why CP1251 if you want UTF-8? What characters *should* it output instead of "???"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UTF-8 is the default encoding for Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader...you should not need to change this at all unless you want the values automatically converted to some other charset.

e.g.

```
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls",true,"UTF-16");
```

to convert outputs to UTF-16

Answer (score 1):

I tried UTF-16 but there's still an error.

Then I tried:

```
$data->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');
$data = new Spreadsheet_Excel_Reader("test.xls",true,"UTF-8");
```

This is ok.

Comment: $excel = new PhpExcelReader();
$excel->setOutputEncoding('UTF-8');

This worked for me after hours of different trials.

Thank You.